# calling java axis2 webservice (with omelement params) from c#

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, apache-axis

I want to call a webservice which expects a OMElement-parameter. How can I serve this with c# / .net?

The signature of the generated client looks like this:

```
client.ExecuteMethod(object param);
```

Thx in advance,
macx

Comment: MacX - have you been able to resolve this? I have a similar problem, it's just unbelievable there is no clear answer. Where have all the experts gone?

Comment: I didn't follow on it, because it was some kind of evaluation for a solution.